# ngFullCalendar Get all empty time slots in dayagenda

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I am using latest version of FullCalendar with their schedule plugin. I can't find how to get all empty slots in an array using DayAgenda view. I am trying to pass an empty object to the empty time slots. I have searched through their documents but couldn't find anything.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. How are you defining your "empty" slots? FullCalendar itself has no concept of empty slots. There are just events. Please show your code and explain in some more detail. Thankyou.

Comment: @ADyson, I want to select all the slots which doesn't have any events.

Comment: In fullCalendar, "slots" are a purely visual thing used to draw the grid in the "agenda" style views. They're not used at all in the other views. There's no data object behind it which the calendar keeps track of. An event can, in any case, cover multiple "slots", or part of a slot, or part / all of many slots. fullCalendar doesn't care, it just deals with events in terms of precise start and end times. It's up to you to define what rules you use to restrict that, and to define what you want a slot to be, if you want to fix the length of them or stop events going into certain places.

Comment: fullCalendar provides some callback hooks which can help you to integrate the implementation of those rules into the flow of operations in the calendar's UI, that's all. The rest is up to you.